# ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.Controller = INFO,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

error trace:

> log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
>   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
>   Oct 13, 2015 1:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

where is error appender in code i dont get it

Update:

Writing code how i am using log

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class);
logger.info("200 OK");
logger.error("Incorrect json format");
```

Comment: is log4j.properties is in your classpath

Comment: it is in src/main/resources folder

Comment: please try after moving it to src/main folder

Comment: not working same eror

Comment: please try one more :) , try to move in scr/main/java , i think your log4j is not detecting, so it is calling other one

Comment: not working same error

Comment: It seems, u r using Spring MVC. Could u plz share the details- how u trying to load u log4j configuration file and how u trying to do the logging ?

Comment: Yeah i am using Spring MVC

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your log4j.properties file,

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and its only appender to stdout
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# stdout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

See more in [*Apache log4j 2.x documentation guide*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html).